# Java storing password in an object for future use in api?

Tags: java, jira, password-protection, jira-rest-java-api

Essentially I am using the jira api to allow customers of the software to view all open issues. They are then able to comment on it through the api.

My issue arises in that I need to submit their username and password to add the comment. I am currently storing them in an object when they originally login, I am doing a two-legged login as a developer account to allow them to view issues under other projects.

I'm not really sure the best way of expanding this. It's obviously wrong to keep the user credentials in an object for future use right? What's the best way to change this as I need to use their credentials later?

Comment: Not obviously wrong, no.  If the app itself is secure, there shouldn't be a way to compromise the password.  But security is hard, so better safe than sorry.  The usual way is to log in once, and receive a "cookie" from the server, then use that cookie to log in on all subsequent operations.

Comment: @markspace that makes sense, thank for you the simple explanation, I will have a look if I can use this method with jira (not that sure I can)